# Android Layout for different width buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imagebutton

I'm trying to create a layout with 6 different ImageButtons and even after reading many layout tutorials and docs I'm getting nowhere.
I am trying to create this:
Always portrait, images' indvidual height & width must stay same scale, anchored to screen bottom with system navigation buttons showing:

```
    ----------------------------
    |                          |
    |                          |
    |                          |
    |                          |
    |       BACKGROUND         |
    |                          |
    |                          |
    |                          |
    |                          |
    |                          |
    |--------------------------|                          
    |   SM   |    MD   |   LG  |
    |--------------------------|
    |        FirstNight        |
    |--------------------------|
    |  NightWith  |NightWithout|
    ----------------------------
```

Below is the latest version of the code I have for ImageButtons Night, NightWithConstable and NightWithoutConstable. The result of the code is nothing like what is expected:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/appsalempicsmaller"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/nightWithConstableButton"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonnightwithconstable"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:background="#00ffffff"

            android:adjustViewBounds="true"

            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:onClick="nightButtonOnClick"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/nightWithoutConstableButton"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonnightwithoutconstable"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:background="#74ffffff"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nightWithConstableButton" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/firstNightButton"
        android:src="@drawable/buttonfirstnight"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:background="#7cffffff"

        android:clickable="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:onClick="firstNightButtonOnClick"
        android:layout_above="@+id/nightWithConstableButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I haven't even bothered with the layout for the SM, ND, and LG buttons because I'm obviously missing something fundamental already.

Input and sage advice for creating the desired layout are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="4"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linerLayout">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sm"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bdm"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:background="#00ffffff" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/md"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bdm"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:background="#00ffffff"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Lg"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bdm"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:background="#00ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/FirstNight"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_bdm"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:background="#00ffffff" />
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/NightWith"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_bdm"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:onClick="nightButtonOnClick" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/NightWithout"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_bdm"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:onClick="nightButtonOnClick"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```